# How do tablespaces differ in DB2 from databases in MySQL or SQL Server?

Tags: db2, tablespaces

In DB2, it seems there is a strong separation between what a database is and what a tablespace is. Where as in MySQL and MS SQL Server tablespace and database seemed to be used synonymously.

What are the differences, if any?

Comment: That's not strictly correct.  In SQL Server speak, tablespaces are called filegroups.  A SQL Server database is something like a schema in Oracle or DB2, but is more autonomous.  It has its own permissions, data dictionary, configuration and schema namespace.  A database is more like a mini instance than an Oracle/DB2 schema but does not require a whole separate process.  You can also run multiple SQL Server instances if you feel so inclined.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells Yeah well, that would have been pretty good information as part of an answer then, wouldn't it? But instead, you chose to vote to close this instead of giving a good complete answer for future reference. Thanks for the comment, I guess.

Comment: The question was closed because it was poorly worded and seemed to contain some incorrect assumptions.  Unfortunately the moderation process has to be fairly ruthless about this sort of stuff or the forums would be overrun with drivel and rendered useless.  If you fix up your basic research and clarify the question then ping the mods on The Heap you can get it re-opened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In DB2, a tablespace is the object that serves as a layer of abstraction between tables (and indexes) and disk.  It is similar to a file group in MS SQL Server.

In DB2, a database is roughly equivalent to a SQL Server instance – a database contains multiple tablespaces, transaction logs, one or more bufferpools and other memory areas.

A "database" in SQL server is much closer to a *schema* in DB2.

Comment: Although a Database in SQL Server can have schemas as well.